# How to calculate the variance of an array in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have the following array which I need to figure out its variance:

```
julia> a = [5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 12, 17, 67, 68, 69, 72, 74, 74, 92, 93, 100, 105, 110, 120, 124]
21-element Vector{Int64}:
   5
   6
   7
   8
  10
  12
  12
  17
  67
  68
   ⋮
  74
  74
  92
  93
 100
 105
 110
 120
 124
```

How can I do this in Julia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Julia has `var` function in built into standard `Statistics` module. So you can just do:

```
using Statistics
var(a)
```

The StatsBase.jl package does not export the `var` function, so your code would not work when used in a fresh Julia session. You would have to write `StatsBase.var(a)` instead (or add `using Statistics`).

What StatsBase.jl adds to the `var` function is that it defines additional methods that allow computation of weighted variance. So e.g. the following works with StatsBase.jl (but would currently not work without it):

```
julia> using Statistics

julia> using StatsBase

julia> var([1,2,3], Weights([1,2,3]))
0.5555555555555555
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone wants to calculate variance from first principles, you can do this:

```
function my_variance(x)
    n = length(x)
    μ = sum(x) / n
    sum((x .- μ) .^ 2) / (n - 1)
end
```

But please, just use `StatsBase.var`!